# Using find() inside forEach loop in javascript/es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays - `array 1` and `array 2`. I want to update `newName` property of `array1` items if that item exists in `array2`. I have below code to do this task

```
array1.forEach((array1Item) => {
   const foundItem = array2.find(array2Item => array2Item.id === array1Item.id);                   
   if (foundItem) {                      
    array1Item.newName = foundItem.name;                  
   }           
})
```

I want to know if there is any better (or modern) way to do write this piece of code using es6 functions.

Comment: But you are using ES6...

Comment: did you mean `array1Item.newName = foundItem.name; `?

Comment: yes I am ..but want to know if there is any better way to do this :)

Comment: @TKoL: yes sorry...edited the question

Comment: You should define "better". What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a good idea to create a hash from id to item for `array2` and use that to get the new names.

```
const idsToArray2 = array2.reduce( (acc, current) => 
 { 
  acc[current.id]=current; 
  return acc
 }, {})

array1.forEach((array1Item) => {
   const foundItem = idsToArray2[array1Item.id];                   
   if (foundItem) {                      
    array1.newName = foundItem.name;                  
   }           
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take two separate loops and collect in the first all `id`/`name` and map in the second new objects without mutating some data.

```
const
    names = array2.reduce((m, { id, name: newName }) => m.set(id, { newName }), new Map),
    result = array1.map(o => ({ ...o, ...names.get(o.id) }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve the same in this way. First create an index for `array2` and then map the `array1` as per item found inside the `indexed` object.

```
const indexed = array2.reduce((o, c) => ({...o, [c['id']]: c}), {});
array1 = array1.map(item => {
    if (indexed[item.id]) return {...item, newName: indexed[item.id].name};
    return item;
})
```